# How do I store multiple Integers from one input on the same line?

Tags: java

In my programm, I would like to know if I am storing the indices correctly and how to have the user input the indices on the same line without jumping lines.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StirngFun {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word;
    int index1;
    int index2;
    int index3;
    int index4;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a word:");
    word = kb.next();
    System.out.print("Enter four indices:");
    index1 = kb.nextInt();
    index2 = kb.nextInt();
    index3 = kb.nextInt();
    index4 = kb.nextInt();

    }


}
```

Comment: It's not clear quite what you're asking, but the answer is almost certainly that you should be using an array or a `List` instead.

Comment: well the program ask the user for a word, second it asks for four numbers which will be the indexes of the word so it can make a word out of those indexes and my problem is how to store all those numbers on the same line @chrylis and we have gotten to arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. Just one thing. Assuming you want the user to press enter after entering a word here :  `System.out.print("Enter a word:");` then you just have to make a minor change:

`word = kb.nextLine();`

The rest is fine. reading the input like this:

```
index1 = kb.nextInt();
index2 = kb.nextInt();
index3 = kb.nextInt();
index4 = kb.nextInt();
```

means that your `Scanner` has the default delimiter of `" "` so the input should be like that:

```
Enter a word: "Whatever"
Enter four indices: 1 2 3 4
```

The numbers should be seperated by a space. Hope this helps